# SignalR client (Xamarin) doesn't get messages when sending to a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms, signalr

My problem is:
I have a WPF app and a Xamarin Forms app. I want to create a chat. And it works when I call from WPF to a method that should send a message to every user. But it doesn't when I choose a specific user. In that case the "On" method on the Xamarin site is not fired. Probably I messed up something with logging a user. Here is my code.

**Xamarin**

```
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("my_url");
            hubConnection.Headers.Add("login", CacheUtils.User.login);

            ChatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            await hubConnection.Start();


            ChatHubProxy.On<string, string>("UpdateChatMessage", (message, username) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "AddMessage", new Message() { Text = message, User = username });
                });
            });               

            string lConnectionId = await ChatHubProxy.Invoke<string>("Login");
            hubConnection.ConnectionId = lConnectionId;
```

So I basically create a connection and subscribe to an "On" method. In the header I pass a user login. As I said before receiving messages works when the message is for everyone. 
On the server side I first call a method "Login" which adds user to my ConcurrentDictionary. Then in a method "SendMessageToSpecificUser" I get user from this dictionary I call "UpdateChatMessage".

**Server side**

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    public void SendMessage(string message, string username)
    {
        Clients.All.UpdateChatMessage(message, username); //this works
    }

    public void SendMessageToSpecificUser(string message, string login)
    {
        string lUserId = clients.Where(x => x.Value == login).FirstOrDefault().Key;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lUserId))
            Clients.User(lUserId).UpdateChatMessage(message, login); //this doesn't work
    }        

    public string Login()
    {
        string username = Context.Headers.Get("login");
        if (clients.ContainsKey(username))
            ((IDictionary)clients).Remove(username);

        clients.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, username);

        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I should use:

> `Clients.Client(lUserId).UpdateChatMessage(message, login);`

instead of

> `Clients.User(lUserId).UpdateChatMessage(message, login);`

Comment: Hi , glad found the solution ! Remeber to mark this when you can . :-)