# How can I run the Signal server on an Android device&

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, signalr

How can I run the SignalR server on an Android device to exchange messages with another android device? I want to write a P2P chat on xamarin forms. Tell me what to read on this topic.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags (such as `[visual-studio]` - your question isn't about using the Visual Studio application, which is what the tag is for - check the tag description for more info).

Comment: You can refer to below threads:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987340/signalr-client-xamarin-doesnt-get-messages-when-sending-to-a-specific-user   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-realtime-app-with-signalr-asp-net-core/